# Initial response from Dialogflow fulfillment library takes very long (30 sec)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Using the [dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) for connecting Dialogflow to the Zendesk web widget, I experience a very long delay (about 30 sec) only with the initial request e.g. by just entering "hello" to trigger Default Welcome intent. All subsequent requests are fulfilled immediately.

This occurs with a custom Node.js script deployed on Firebase, it does not happen when testing under localhost using the Firebase emulator.

I seem not to be able to obtain any useful logging output from Firebase in order to understand where the delay is coming from. The delay happens after calling sessionClient.detectIntent(request):

```
console.timeLog("process", "Dialogflow Request");
const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
console.timeLog("process", "Dialogflow Response");//continues 30 seconds later at very first request
```

The only observation I have is that the request arrives this late in the onRequest function:

```
exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
console.log("onRequest Function triggered");//happens after 30 secs
//...
})
```

There is no error shown in the Firebase logs, and the onRequest fulfillment function finishes successfully after a few ms.

I would be thankful for getting some hints on how to troubleshoot this issue since I am currently out of ideas.

Comment: Could you please provide further details about the fulfillment end? Not sure either how you use Firebase in conjunction with Dialogflow. Please edit your question with further information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, @FernandoC. I use the Dialogflow ES console and have enabled "Enable webhook call for this intent" under "Fulfillment" for all of my intents.
On the "Fulfillment" tab I have activated the option "Webhook" and use the firebase url where my functions are hosted, something like:
https://us-central1-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/fulfillment
I also use the Node library dialogflow-fulfillment, if this is relevant.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but in some rare cases, the fulfillment does not start to respond at all, and in very few cases I got this error message back:
`sessionClient ERROR: Error: ECONNRESET undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: socket hang up`

Comment: Could be related to something called "cold start". Will try to try out the suggestions given in this video, but it will take some time until I can report back:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM

Comment: @MariusWilhelmi Have you resolved this? I m also facing the same issue.